# Looking for a source of data for these specific United States Demographics for People and Businesses

Tags: data-request, usa, us-census, demographics

**UPDATE:**

Ok as I'm learning more about this stuff, I'm realizing that I need Demographics and Firmographics, but more granular then the Census data. As the Census data is 35-44 years of age and I need 35-39 for example

**Original:**

Sorry for if I come across as ignorant. I usually hangout over at StackOverflow and StackGis sent me here. I'm a developer and a client has specific demographics needs that I'm not sure where to get. I looked at some Census data, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Example: the client wants to know how many 35-39 year old people live in a given 1, 2, 3, 5 mile radius, but Census only has 35-44 year old grouping from what I can tell.

Does anyone know who would be a reliable source for all of the following?

It would need to be something I can download and import, or even better it has an API I can tap into.

In regards to people, distance from a point, 1, 2, 3, 5 miles: How many..

- 35-39 Year Olds
- Households with no Children
- 1 Person Living in a Household
- 2 People Living in a Household
- Household Income 75k Higher
- Units In Structure - 1 Attached Unit
- Home Values worth 1 Mill
- Renter Occupied Median Rent amount

Business Demo Info, distance from a point, 1, 2, 3, 5 miles: How many..

- Businesses (Count)
- Other Food Services
- Furniture Stores
- Garden Stores, Bldg Material Stores, Hardware Stores (Can be combined to one number)
- Garden Percent of total business are Transportation, Communication, Utilities

Comment: you are looking for the decennial census summary files

Answer (score 2):

You can get census data on population by single year on a county basis here:

https://www.census.gov/popest/data/datasets.html

I can't recall seeing it published down at the tract/block level (more of what the asker is asking) broken down by single year. You can find it in the 10 year increments as was noted in the question.